# R Switch statement combined with more complex interactions such as %in%

Tags: r, class, switch-statement

Is there any way to use multi-selectivity (e.g. `switch` statements) with more complex requirements in R?
Specifically, it seems sub-optimal to need to write the following:

```
if(is.POSIXct(value)) {
  ...
} else if(is.integer(value)) {
  ...
} else if(is.double(value)) {
  ...
}
```

I mean, `switch(typeof(value), ...` almost works, except that it doesn't work for classes like dates.
I'm thinking something like `%in%` would be really handy if it were possible to use in combination with a `switch` statement.

Comment: Are you looking for `case_when`? It's documentation can be found [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html)

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve?  It seems like you might want to look at defining dispatch methods for your function.

Comment: @Ritchie I'm looking to add columns to a data.table and want them to be well-typed for when I insert values. The columns need to be empty, and I don't want to leave them as Logical (the default) before the part where I insert values into the appropriate cells

Comment: @benson23 That looks very much what I'm looking for. Would you be able to post that as an answer

Comment: @Warpspace Without actual data it's difficult to provide a tailored solution to your problem.